Laravel Development Server Closing Connections Immediately After Starting
Issue:
When I start the Laravel development server, it closes connections immediately after they are opened. Here is the output from the terminal:

RAJ@RAJ-SAMSE MINGW64 ~/desktop/a2i/task-manager (master)
php artisan serve --port=8080
Starting Laravel development server: http://127.0.0.1:8080
[Sat Jun  8 19:11:46 2024] PHP 8.2.12 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8080) started
[Sat Jun  8 19:15:46 2024] 127.0.0.1:52129 Accepted
[Sat Jun  8 19:16:10 2024] 127.0.0.1:52129 Closing
[Sat Jun  8 19:16:10 2024] 127.0.0.1:52130 Accepted
[Sat Jun  8 19:16:10 2024] 127.0.0.1:52130 Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection
[Sat Jun  8 19:16:10 2024] 127.0.0.1:52130 Closing
[Sat Jun  8 19:16:10 2024] 127.0.0.1:52185 Accepted
[Sat Jun  8 19:16:10 2024] 127.0.0.1:52185 Closing
[Sat Jun  8 19:16:10 2024] 127.0.0.1:52188 Accepted
[Sat Jun  8 19:16:11 2024] 127.0.0.1:52188 Closing

I’m encountering an issue with my Laravel project where the development server closes connections immediately after they are opened. Here are the details of my setup and the steps I've taken so far:
Environment:
OS: Windows 10
XAMPP Version: 8.2.12 (includes PHP 8.2.12 and MariaDB 10.4.32)
Laravel Version: 8.x
PHP Version: 8.2.12
Steps Taken:
Project Setup:
Cloned the Laravel project into the directory: ~/desktop/a2i/task-manager.
Ensured Composer dependencies are installed using composer install.
Database Configuration:
Created a MySQL database named task_manager.
Updated the .env file with the following database configuration

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=task_manager2.0
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Running Migrations:
Successfully ran the database migrations using php artisan migrate.
Clearing Configuration Cache:
Cleared and cached the configuration using

php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear

Starting the Laravel Development Server:
Started the server using php artisan serve --port=8080.
Additional Information:
I confirmed the MySQL service is running and accessible.
The PHP modules for mysqli and pdo_mysql are enabled.
I’ve checked the storage/logs/laravel.log file, but it doesn’t provide any additional information related to this issue.


the error message does not seem to have anything to do with javascript or database 2) you are using mariadb and not mysql. No, the two are not the same.

